# why org.apache.coyote.http11.http11protocol is removed in tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat8

My application upgraded to tomcat 8 and now unable to start due to missing class **org.apache.coyote.http11.http11protocol** for protocol attribute in server.xml.

Answer (score 5):

Please change the

`org.apache.coyote.http11.http11protocol`

to

`org.apache.coyote.http11.http11NioProtocol`.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just found this today.  Note that in my version I had letter case issues.  For me it was "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" .  The class name needed an upper case "H".